# TCPDF - Set page background then re-enable header image on 1 page

Tags: php, tcpdf

been messing around using the TCPDF examples, 
I've built out a report I would like to run, 4 pages,

the first couple of pages, from 1-2 are just background images, 
ie: (1st page) front cover, (background image)
    (2nd page) summary image (background image)
    (3rd page) this is where background image is removed and use the standard header
    (4th page) back to using a full background image,

I'm using code from the example example_051.php including the extended class which Im assuming is overwritting the main Header function used by TCPDF,

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // get the current page break margin
        $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
        // get current auto-page-break mode
        $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
        // disable auto-page-break
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
        // set bacground image
        if($this->page <= 1){
          $img_file = 'frontcover.jpg';
              $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
        }
        // restore auto-page-break status
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
        // set the starting point for the page content
        $this->setPageMark();
    }
}

// PAGE 1 - BIG background image
$pdf->AddPage();
$bMargin = $pdf->getBreakMargin();
$auto_page_break = $pdf->getAutoPageBreak();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
$img_file = 'frontcover.jpg';
$pdf->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
$pdf->setPageMark();


// PAGE 2 - BIG background image
$pdf->AddPage();
$bMargin = $pdf->getBreakMargin();
$auto_page_break = $pdf->getAutoPageBreak();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
$img_file = 'frontpage-summary.jpg';
$pdf->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
$pdf->setPageMark();


// PAGE 3 - SET Header image
$pdf->setPrintHeader(true); // enable header
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);// disable footer
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetHeaderData("header.png", PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, "image title", "header string");

$pdf->AddPage();
$html.= '<div style="padding:10px;">';
$html.= '<h2>Report Title</h2>';
$html.= '<h3>sub title</h3>';
$html.= '<h2>Other Title</h2>';
$html.= '<h3>sub title</h3>';
$html.= '<h2>Other Title</h2>';
$html.= '<h3>sub title</h3>';
$html.= '</div>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


// PAGE 4
$pdf->AddPage();
$bMargin = $pdf->getBreakMargin();
$auto_page_break = $pdf->getAutoPageBreak();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
$img_file = 'final-page.png';
$pdf->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
$pdf->setPageMark();
$pdf->lastPage();
```

Iv tried to reset the header using the resetHeaderTemplate() function, 
but the header portion on page 3 wont show up?

In the extended class, I have a little check to see if the page is less than 1,

```
if($this->page <= 1){
   $img_file = 'frontcover.jpg';
   $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
}
```

what i did was copy the entire header function from the TCPDF.php into the if else
so now it reads

```
if($this->page <= 1){
   $img_file = 'frontcover.jpg';
   $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
}else{
   // add the entire code from the original function :(
}
```

that seems to be the only way i can get my original header back on page 3..
any one else have any ideas on how to set / reset the header?

cheers